# Function should be called on each calculation

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm getting this error

> line 205: The function 'ta.change' should be called on each
> calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call
> from the ternary operator or from the scope.

I'm trying but I can't fix it. It's an indicator on tradingview name: OBV MACD Indicator by RafaelZioni, which I want to convert to pine script v5.

```
p = 1,src15=tt1
b5 = 0.,dev5 = 0.,oc = 0
n5 = ta.cum(1) - 1
a15 = ta.cum(math.abs(src15 - nz(b5[1],src15)))/n5*p
b5 := src15 > nz(b5[1],src15) + a15 ? src15 : src15 < nz(b5[1],src15) - a15 ? src15 : nz(b5[1],src15)
//----
dev5 := ta.change(b5) ? a15 : nz(dev5[1],a15)

//----
oc := ta.change(b5) > 0 ? 1 : ta.change(b5) < 0 ? -1 : nz(oc[1]) //-->this is the line 205 error
//----
cs = oc == 1 ? color.blue : color.red
//change(oc)>0
plot(b5,color=cs,linewidth=4,transp=50)
//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is a **warning**, not an error.

It happens because you are calling a function within the ternary operator. If you want to get rid of this warning message, you should extract it from the ternary operator as the warning message says.

Below code will fix it

```
//----
_change_b5 = ta.change(b5)
dev5 := _change_b5 ? a15 : nz(dev5[1],a15)

//----
oc := _change_b5 > 0 ? 1 : _change_b5 < 0 ? -1 : nz(oc[1])
//----
```